# How to complete this program?

Tags: c#

I wanted to create a small test program, where the program asks you to select the number of "contestants", enter their names, their favorite singer, everyone voted singer chosen by others and draw up a ranking.

I'm at the beginning and I still have much to do...but I started to write a little code. Here it is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ciao,Benvenuto/a a 'Vota Cantante', il nuovo gioco in cui puoi votare il tuo cantante preferito.");
        Console.Write("Premi INVIO sulla tastiera per continuare..");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("(NOTA BENE: Sono necessari almeno due giocatori per poter giocare) Indica il numero dei giocatori: ");
        int GiocatoriN = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string[] ArrayGiocatori = new string[GiocatoriN];

        for (int i = 0; i < GiocatoriN; i++)
        {
            Giocatori Gio = new Giocatori();
            Gio.NomeECantante();
        } 
    }

    class Giocatori
    {
        public void NomeECantante()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inserisci il tuo nome: ");
            string Giocatore =Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(Giocatore + " inserisci il tuo cantante preferito: ");
            string CantantePreferito = Console.ReadLine();
            CantantePreferito.ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine("Dai un voto da 1 a 10 a " + CantantePreferito + ": ");
            int Voto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

For the moment I have two questions.

The program works, but I thought to instantiate the class you need a constructor, but I managed to create it without. So are constructors obligatory?

I could put this piece of code in the constructor, and not in the method. but little change:

(Even if it was possible to put it in the constructor)

```
Console.WriteLine("Inserisci il tuo nome: ");
            string Giocatore = Console.ReadLine();
```

The second question is: I wanted the program to create a new player for the amount of GiocatoriN, so if you made that players were 3, I wanted to create 3 objects.

I gave the name Gio, inside the for loop, and at the beginning I had written thus, it's giving me an error though:

```
for (int i= 0; i<GiocatoriN; i++)
        {
            Giocatori Gio[i] = new Giocatori();
            Gio.NomeECantante();
```

I had tried to use Gio [GiocatoriN] but the error remains.

As it is, I repeat the method NomeECantante() for the number of selected players, but I overwrite every time over at Gio, storing only the last player, no? (I mean the code without error).

So what am I supposed to do next?

Comment: You get a default constructor for free.

Comment: The reason you are getting an error is because you are not initializing the `Gio` array. Before the `for` loop, put this: `Giocatori[] Gio = new Giocator[GlocatoriN];`. Inside the loop, use this: `Gio[i] = new Giocatlori();`

Comment: However, I can no longer do Gio. NomeECantante ();

Error = Only assignments, calls etc. can be used as instructions

Comment: @GuglielmoAstro Did you google the error in order to make an attempt at understanding what it is, why it's happening, and to see if anyone else has encountered this same problem and resolved it already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many problem in your code and I will try to explain them one by one:

First, you need to rewrite your class Giocatore:

```
class Giocatore
{
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public string CantantePreferito {get;set;}
    public int Voto {get;set;}

    public Giocatore(string nome, string cantante, int voto)
    {
       this.Nome = nome;
       this.CantantePreferito = cantante;
       this.Voto = voto;
    }
}
```

Here I have removed the method that get the inputs. I have added some public properties to have an instance of the class Giocatore preserve its internal values and added a constructor that gets the three values. Your current code declares the variable as local to the `NomeECantante` method and as such they are lost when you exit from that method.
(The constructor could also be omitted but having it will make life easier when you build an instance of `Giocatore`)

Now in main code you change your logic to something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ....
    int GiocatoriN;
    if(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out GiocatoriN))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a number please");
        return;
    }

    List<Giocatore> giocatori = new List<Giocatore>();

    for (int i = 0; i < GiocatoriN; i++)
    {
        Giocatore g = LoadGiocatoreData();
        if(g == null)
          return;
        giocatori.Add(g);
    } 
}
```

Here I have added some checking on the input entered and removed the useless string array to use a `List<Giocatore>` that allows adding any number of elements.
Finally the input of the data for a new Giocatore is located in a method external to the class

```
 public Giocatore LoadGiocatoreData()
 {
     string nome;
     string cantante;
     int voto;

     Console.WriteLine("Inserisci il tuo nome: ");
     nome = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine(nome + " inserisci il tuo cantante preferito: ");
     string cantante = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine("Dai un voto da 1 a 10 a " + cantante + ": ");
     if(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out voto))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Please insert a number");
         return null;
     }

     Giocatore g = new Giocatore(nome, cantante, voto);
     return g;
 }
```

At this point the List in the main method contains the  elements of type Giocatore that your user has requested ath the beginning of your code. You could check this by a simple loop like this

```
 foreach(Giocatore g in giocatori)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Giocatore:" + g.Nome);
     Console.WriteLine("Cantante:" + g.CantantePreferito);
     Console.WriteLine("Voto:" + g.Voto.ToString());
     Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------);
 }
```

Comment: Now I try, thanks.

Many things I have not yet studied. the List for example, still do not know them. One more question:

If the Player class, not adding public properties, I can't use them outside the method, for example in the Main? Can I use them only within the same method?

Comment: Once you have defined the class, you could create instances of that class anywhere in your project, provided the class is in the same namespace or add the using 'namespace' at the beginning of your source file. Instead if you talk about the List variable then you need to make it public. But this is another question.

Comment: I mean this:

string name;

string singer;

int rating;


Console.WriteLine ("enter your name:");

name = console::ReadLine();


Instead of:


Console.WriteLine ("enter your name:");

 STRING nome= console.ReadLine ();



Then how did you, can I use Name, singer and vote out by the method or class?

Comment: These are local variables. Their value is inserted in the Giocatore instance. It is this instance that goes out of the method with its properties (user input value in response to ReadLine)

Comment: If you do not declare at the top of the class Giocatore can't use them out of the method?

As I did I was okay? check out my initial code

Answer (score 1):

If no constructor is given, the compiler add a default constructor

```
class Foo
{
}
```

is the same of

```
class Foo
{
   public Foo()
   {
   }
}
```

for the other question, try

```
Giocatori Gio = new Giocatori(); //create new instance of Giocatori
Gio.NomeECantante(); //invoke method NomeECantante
ArrayGiocatori[i] = Gio; //save instance inside array at index i
```

also `Giocatori` is wrong (think about is as Giocatore, a class who contains all info of a player) and add a field for every property you want to store.

```
class Giocatori
{
    public string Name;
    public string CantantePreferito;
    public int Voto;

    public void NomeECantante()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inserisci il tuo nome: ");
        Nome =Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(Giocatore + " inserisci il tuo cantante preferito: ");
        CantantePreferito = Console.ReadLine();
        // not
        //string CantantePreferito = Console.ReadLine();
        // otherwise you create a local variable with same name instead of set field Cantante

        Console.WriteLine("Dai un voto da 1 a 10 a " + CantantePreferito + ": ");
        Voto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

after to can print all player like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < GiocatoriN; i++)
    {
        Giocatori Gio = ArrayGiocatori[i];
        Console.WriteLine("a {0} piace sentir cantare {1} (voto {2}, Gio.Nome, Gio.CantantePreferito, Gio.Voto);
    }
```

Comment: Except `ArrayGiocatori` is of type string[]. He needs to change that to a list or an array of Giocatori objects.

Comment: "unable to convert "class Giocatori ..." to in the string"

Comment: @Guglielmo change the declaration of ArrayGiocatori to be a Giocatori[] instead of a string[]

Comment: If I do Giocatori [] ArrayGiocatori =  Giocatoris [GiocatoriN]; I by mistake.

Sorry, but I am at the beginning, are not good

Answer (score 0):

For your first question about constructor, the program provides a default constructor for every class if you dont write one. So it exists there just that you cabt see it. 
For second questiin you need to first define array of objects and then you can assign individual elements to it.

```
Giocatori[] array = new Giocatori[3];
foreach(Giocatori g in array)
{
    g = new Giocatori();
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yes a typo! Geez m on mobile :-P

Comment: You haven't added anything to the array, so what are you trying to iterate over? Also, you can't assign to the variable you are using as the iteration variable, it gives a compile time error. You can fix it by using a for loop and saying something like array[i] = new Giocatori()